# Use WP_Meta_Query To List All Values For 1 Key On Page Template

Tags: custom-field

I only want to query all values for 1 key on 1 page template. Is this possible using WP_Meta_Query? I know i can use get_post_custom_values however can i use any other functions? Its a page template with dozens of custom fields using the same key and different values.

```
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $args );

    $args = array(
            'key' => 'key'
    )
);
```

Edit. How do i print the values using these args?

```
$args = array(
      'p'         => 75, 
      'post_type' => 'any',
      'meta_key' => 'key',
);
```

Comment: You want to search for all meta values corresponding to a given meta key, regardless of post IDs ? Is the meta data saved under the same post ID or multiple post IDs?

Comment: @birgire For only 1 page as its a page template which uses the same key but different values. I know i can use get_post_custom_values but can i use a query?

Comment: Then you have a single post ID. It's not clear why you dont want to use get_post_custom_values() and want to use WP_Meta_Query or someting else? The WP_Meta_Query helps with generating SQL for meta queries. What about get_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', false ) ?

Comment: Just wanted to try another way to do it using a query that only uses custom field data from 1 page. Is this possible? See edit.